# How do you ADD color banding to video (using Adobe Creative Suite)?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, color-grading

I like to introduce distortions and color effects into my videos when I edit them. How can I recreate color banding in After Effects or Premiere Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Adding colour banding is also known as posterising (or posterizing if that's how you roll). There's a built-in (to AE, though I'd be surprised if it's not also in PP) posterize effect (**Effects>Stylize>Posterize**). It only has one control, Level, if you set it low you'll get something that looks like an 8-bit game, or a screen-printed poster (hence the name):

[image]

Or if you set it higher you get banding:

[image]

If you want a bit more control the Cartoon effect (**Effects>Stylize>Cartoon**) also give you pronounced banding. Set the render style to **Fill** (default is **Fill & Edges**), and then twiddle the knobs.